# mysql join only returning the first row when it should be multiple

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I am trying to retrieve information from two tables, user and meta. However, I am only getting the first row instead of all of them.

User table looks like this

```
ID | Display Name | Email
1  | Test         | test@test.com
```

Meta table looks like this

```
meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
123     | 1       | address  | 123 somewhere
123     | 1       | city     | Metropolis
```

This is my query

```
$query = $this->db->from('users as u');
$query = $this->db->join('meta as m', 'u.ID = m.user_id');
$query = $this->db->where('ID', $data['ID']);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->row_array();
```

but I get everything for the user table, but only the first row of the meta table. Trying to get all the rows that match user_id = 1 in the meta table.

What am I missing in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to retrieve all result of the query or just the first row?

```
$query = $this->db->from('users as u');
$query = $this->db->join('meta as m', 'u.ID = m.user_id');
$query = $this->db->where('ID', $data['ID']);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Getting just one result use:
`row_array()` returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an array.

```
return $query->row_array();
```

Getting an array of results use:
`result_array()` method returns the query result in pure array

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: result_array was exactly what I need, now to parse through the array :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it may be helpful

```
$this->db->select('u.*, m.*');
$this->db->from('users as u');
$this->db->join('meta as m', 'u.ID = m.user_id');
$this->db->where('u.ID', $data['ID']);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->row_array();
```

Comment: were getting close. now I am getting two variables from the second table "meta_key" and "meta_value". How can I save it so that for row 1, Address becomes the variable and meta_value is the value of it?

Comment: if you want only "meta_key" and "meta_value" then just use $this->db->select('m.meta_key, m.meta_value')

Comment: And if you want only a single row then return $query->row(). You will get only first row

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->reset_query();       
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->join('meta', 'user.id = meta.id ' );
$this->db->where('user.id="'. $data['ID'].'"'); // where conditions
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```